# Delete query in empty database

Tags: database, oracle, performance

I am working with oracle database and I have a lot of queries in a file. My problem is that this file execute very slow.
Some queries in file are delete and I know that, in this moment, database is empty.
So, what happens if I delete "delete queries"? Is better? Talking about performance.

Comment: It's impossible to say, unless you know how long those delete queries take.

Comment: So, delete queries in empty database take time?

Comment: Everything takes some amount of time. In an empty database, select queries should not take much time, nor updates.

Comment: Unless they are doing full table scans and you have a lot of empty blocks (i.e. high water mark set after previous deletion of a lot of data), which can make everything slow. Truncating the empty tables might help, but be sure they really are - and are supposed to be - empty first.